# Create array mask from randomly ordered list

Tags: python, arrays, mask

I have a dataset made of velocity data on an unstructured grid from a CFD simulation, in the structure:

```
data = [[x1, y1, u1, v1], ... , [xn, yn, un, vn]]
```

I need to have a regular grid inside the area covered by this data. However, I do not have information about the boundaries of the x, y domain other than the x, y values itself. The boundary is defined by a complex geometrical shape.

My solution would be to create a rectangular grid with `numpy.mgrid` and then construct an array mask to mask out areas with no data.

But I have no idea how to get a mask just from the randomly ordered coordinates. I tried using scipy's ConvexHull to find the boundaries but it is a concave problem. However, even if I had the boundary points, I am not sure how to create the mask from it, since the indices are not the same as in the regular grid.
How to determine this grid? Is there any other possibility? Maybe its useful to reorder the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I'm *really* unfamiliar with your use-case so I may be way off base here. It sounds like you're effectively looking for the min/max for each coordinate system to create a mask for? Conceptually (maybe not efficient for large datasets):

```
x_min = min([a[0] for a in data])
```

With that I think you'd be able to say something like "the domain of x is `[x_min, x_max]`"

Here's a full example that you can copy/past to see if it produces what you're looking for:

```
from random import randint

# Convenience
def r():
    return randint(-100, 100)


# Generate 100 random coordinates
data = [[r(), r(), r(), r()] for _ in range(0, 100)]

x_min = min([a[0] for a in data])
x_max = max([a[0] for a in data])

y_min = min([a[1] for a in data])
y_max = max([a[1] for a in data])

u_min = min([a[2] for a in data])
u_max = max([a[2] for a in data])

v_min = min([a[3] for a in data])
v_max = max([a[3] for a in data])

print(f'X-Range: {x_min} to {x_max}')
print(f'Y-Range: {y_min} to {y_max}')
print(f'U-Range: {u_min} to {u_max}')
print(f'V-Range: {v_min} to {v_max}')
```

That produces this:

```
X-Range: -98 to 96
Y-Range: -100 to 96
U-Range: -95 to 100
V-Range: -100 to 100
```

While any single entry within `data` might be this:

```
print(data[randint(0, len(data)])

[70, -69, -59, -49]
```